# Delimiter size increased when I am using top alignment inside the \begin{array} which need to be removed. Please provide solution how to solve this

Tags: arrays

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{llll}
\textbf{3} & Write this information in a matrix. Remember to use square brackets. & \textbf{3} &  $\left\{\begin{array}[t]{r@{\hskip0.25em}c@{\hskip0.25em}l}
140 & 58 & 85\cr
200 & 125 & 150\end{array}\right\}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delarray` package provides the solution:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,delarray}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{lp{.6\textwidth}l}
\textbf{3} &
  Write this information in a matrix. Remember to use square brackets. &
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0.25em}%
  $\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{@{}rcl@{}}\rbrack
  140 & 58 & 85\\\
  200 & 125 & 150
  \end{array}$
\\[6ex]
\textbf{4} &
  Write this information in a matrix. Remember to use braces. &
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0.25em}%
  $\begin{array}[t]\lbrace{@{}rcl@{}}\rbrace
  140 & 58 & 85\\\
  200 & 125 & 150
  \end{array}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: excellent choice of package

Comment: Thanks egreg! It's working fine for me. One more challenge i faced when i used colortbl package, \begin{array} contents are disappeared, but it has resolved by commenting \endarray definition inside the colortbl package.

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities, depending on how you want the vertical alignment.  Make sure you use the latest version of `tabstackengine 2018/03/05 (V2.10)`.

**REVISED ANSWER with `rcl` alignment**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llll} \textbf{3} & Write this information in a matrix. 
  Remember to use square brackets. & \textbf{3} & 
  $\left[\tabularCenterstack{rcl}{ 140 & 58 & 85\\ 200 & 125 & 150}\right]$ \end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{llll} \textbf{3} & Write this information in a matrix. 
  Remember to use square brackets. & \textbf{3} & \belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{%
  $\left[\tabularCenterstack{rcl}{ 140 & 58 & 85\\ 200 & 125 & 150}\right]$} \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Inter-column gap can be reset with `\setstacktabulargap{<length>}`, default `\tabcolsep`.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER with left alignment**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llll} \textbf{3} & Write this information in a matrix. 
  Remember to use square brackets. & \textbf{3} & 
  $\bracketMatrixstack{ 140 & 58 & 85\\ 200 & 125 & 150}$ \end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{llll} \textbf{3} & Write this information in a matrix. 
  Remember to use square brackets. & \textbf{3} & \belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{%
  $\bracketMatrixstack{ 140 & 58 & 85\\ 200 & 125 & 150}$} \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted the extra space at the left/right end of the matrix, just add an extra blank column to both ends: `$\bracketMatrixstack{&140 & 58 & 85&\\&200 & 125 & 150&}$`

[image]

Likewise, the declaration, `\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}` can be eliminated if one, instead, uses the `[l]` optional argument on the stack

```
\bracketMatrixstack[l]{ 140 & 58 & 85\\ 200 & 125 & 150}
```

Comment: The OP's `array` has `rcl` columns, so different alignments for the three columns. (I don't know if that's important of course, just thought I'd mention it.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Thanks.  Revised answer provided.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create `\vtop` where first line is strut, then negative skip by `\baselineskip` and then the `\hbox` where your matrix is printed in math. mode.

```
{\bf 3}\quad\vtop{\hbox{\strut}\vskip-\baselineskip\nointerlineskip\hbox{%
$\left\{\matrix{140 & 58 & 85\cr 200 & 125 & 150}\right\}$}}

\bye
```